# What does "Couldn't initialize streams, probably unsupported codec combination" mean?

Tags: rendering, animation, video

What does this mean (boxed in a red box) Please help!! I have so many intros but cant use many because of this problem. Any help?

[image: blender with error message highlighted]

Answer (score 2):

The error means that Blender can't read or write to a specific codec. Speculation based on the screen shot:

your on windows, and probably don't have Ogg/Vorbis codecs installed on your system. You can [download the OpenCodecs package](http://xiph.org/dshow/), which will allow you to play ogg/ogv (vorbis/theora) on windows.

It's generally included in Linux/osx, so your probably getting examples from someone who works in one of those systems.

Or you could try setting the output of your render to a codec you probably already have like Mpeg, h.264, or Windows Media?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after having imported a screen recording into Blender.

The frame rate was set to 29.999. When I changed this to 30, it worked.